# Limit the istream read width for integers

Tags: c++, std, istream

I have a stream which contains data like "1514" and I want to read the two numbers 15 and 14.

I tried to use `std::setw`, but it doesn't seems work for integers.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    stringstream stringStream("1415");
    string s1,s2;
    stringStream>>setw(2)>>s1>>setw(2)>>s2;
    cout<<"s1: "<<s1<<", s2: "<<s2<<endl;

    stringstream intStream("1415");
    int i1,i2;
    intStream>>setw(2)>>i1>>setw(2)>>i2;
    cout<<"i1: "<<i1<<", i2: "<<i2<<endl;
}
```

I want the integers to be parse the way as the strings are done.

So I want that i1=14 and i2=15.

Comment: Read it as a whole and split it later by dividing by 100 (first part) and by modulo 100 (second part)

Comment: The resulting string could be to big to fit into a long.

Comment: Read as string, split in the middle and, if needed, convert each part to `long`/`integer`.

Comment: Indeed setw on input only works for strings. You can exploit that by reading strings and converting them to integers with `strtod` or `stoi`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple approach: first create an array of 3 characters and initialise with null-terminators:

```
char arr[3]{};
```

Extract two characters from the iostream:

```
stringStream.get(arr, 2);
```

Convert the substring to an integer:

```
// alternatives: std::strtol, boost::lexical_cast
std::istringstream subss(arr);
int i1;
subss >> i1;
```

Repeat for the next two digits.

---

Complex approach: Use a parser generator. Following BNF might do the trick:

```
<input>  ::= <i1><i2>
<i1>     ::= <twodig>
<i2>     ::= <twodig>
<twodig> ::= <digit><digit>
```