# How do I take an input and make split it up into different integers?

Tags: c++

So I think the title is a bit confusing, so I'll explain that again here: I would like to have someone input the string "11223344", and have the program set the values of integers to these numbers like so: int a = 11, int b = 22, int c = 33, int d = 44.
Note: This will be used to input save codes for a game I am creating.

```
int PlayerSaveName;
int PLRlvl // level
int PLRmhp // max health
int PLRmap // max armor
int PLRdmg // attack damage
void SelectSave()
{   //----------
    Data_GamePhase = 2;
    WindowTitle();
    system("cls");
    //----------
    std::cout << "Enter your save code.\n";
    std::cout << "Code: ";
    std::cin >> PlayerSaveName;

// PlayerSaveNameFirstSection = PLRlvl;
// PlayerSaveNameSecondSection = PLRmhp;
// PlayerSaveNameThirdSection = PLRmap;
// PlayerSaveNameFourthSection = PLRdmg;
}
```

Comment: Is every integer supposed to be exactly two digits?

Comment: For now yes, but I'm sure I could figure out a way to increase the digits once I have a solution.

Comment: Well, I ask because if you aren't going to use the number of digits to decide where each number begins and ends, you'll have a hard time. Why should `11223344` be `a = 11, b = 22, c = 33, d = 44` instead of `a = 1`, `b = 122`, `c = 334`, `d = 4`?

Comment: You could do something like `std::vector<int> arr; char c1, c2; while (std::cin >> c1 >> c2) arr.push_back((c1-'0')*10 + (c2 - '0'));`

Comment: There's been a misunderstanding: I would like to use the number of digits to decide where the numbers start and end. I simply meant that the two digits per int would limit the maximum value for each statistic to 99(unless a complex algorithm is used) and that I would figure out a way to increase it to 3 or more as I see fit.
(this is a reply to Nathan Pierson)

Comment: Related/dupe: [Limit the istream read width for integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57906646/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string::substr()` and `std::stoi()`, eg:

```
std::string PlayerSaveName;
int PLRlvl; // level
int PLRmhp; // max health
int PLRmap; // max armor
int PLRdmg; // attack damage

void SelectSave()
{
    Data_GamePhase = 2;
    WindowTitle();
    system("cls");

    std::cout << "Enter your save code.\n";
    std::cout << "Code: ";
    std::cin >> PlayerSaveName;

    PLRlvl = std::stoi(PlayerSaveName.substr(0,2));
    PLRmhp = std::stoi(PlayerSaveName.substr(2,2));
    PLRmap = std::stoi(PlayerSaveName.substr(4,2));
    PLRdmg = std::stoi(PlayerSaveName.substr(6,2));

    PlayerSaveNameFirstSection = PLRlvl;
    PlayerSaveNameSecondSection = PLRmhp;
    PlayerSaveNameThirdSection = PLRmap;
    PlayerSaveNameFourthSection = PLRdmg;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For generality, let's define a constant which holds the count of digits in each number:

```
constexpr int sectionSize = 2;
```

Now, we can read `PlayerSaveName` as `std::string` and split it into `std::vector<int>` of sections as follows, assuming that `PlayerSaveName` has multiple of `sectionSize` characters:

```
std::string PlayerSaveName;
// std::cout << ...
std::cin >> PlayerSaveName;
std::vector<int> sections;
for (size_t i = 0; i < PlayerSaveName.size(); i += sectionSize)
{
    int currentNumber = 0;
    for (size_t j = i; j < i + sectionSize; ++j)
    {
        const int currentDigit = PlayerSaveName[j] - '0';
        currentNumber = currentNumber * 10 + currentDigit;
    }
    sections.push_back(currentNumber);
}
```

If we want to make sure that `PlayerSaveName` has proper number of characters, we can, for example, after reading it ask the user to enter the string again if needed, until `PlayerSaveName` is divisible:

```
//...
// std::cout << ...
std::cin >> PlayerSaveName;
while (PlayerSaveName.size() % sectionSize != 0)
{
    std::cout << "Save code is not divisible into " << sectionSize << "-digit numbers, enter again please: ";
    std::cin >> PlayerSaveName;
}
//...
```